# How to mitigate the overfitting problem with lstm, or maybe I'm misunderstanding lstm training?

Tags: python, lstm

My goal is to predict whether a shot is hit or not by the trajectory of the basketball (there are already papers that do the same, I'm just reproducing them (https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03793)). It's a very simple problem, but for some other purpose I want to try lstm's prediction. But the network was not only slow to converge but start overfitting very quickly.
A time series has a length of 12 and a feature dimension of 4 (x,y,z coordinates and time)

```
class PolicyHead(nn.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PolicyHead, self).__init__()
        self.lstm = LSTM(4,64,2,dropout=0.3)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(64,2)

    def forward(self, past_traj):
        b,n,c = past_traj.shape
         
        return self.fc(self.lstm(past_traj, batch_id))
```

[image]

As a comparison a very simple mlp structure was used and the prediction is very good.

```
class PolicyHead(nn.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PolicyHead, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(12*4, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512,512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512,2)
        )

    def forward(self, past_traj):
        b,n,c = past_traj.shape
        return self.fc(past_traj.reshape([b,-1]))
```

[image]

Comment: You probably need to do some hyperparameter tuning, i.e. perhaps adjust the dimension of your LSTM and/or the learning rate. Your MLP has much higher dimension that the LSTM

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually the dimensions of the mlp are quite arbitrary, if lowering the dimensions can achieve similar results. If you increase the dimensionality of lstm (say 512) the network will be completely overfitted within a few epochs

Comment: I think it's actually underfitting - the LSTM training loss isn't as low as the MLP.

Comment: You're right, but as the step increases lstm's loss eventually drops to a very low level, except I lost the previous results. If the dimension is increased to 512, the loss will decrease to close to 0 within 5 epochs.

Comment: But have you found a point where increasing the LSTM dimension no longer results in the minimum test loss getting lower?

Comment: Yes, hardly any improvement

Answer (score 0):

Your graph does suggest overfitting, especially if it continues to increase if more epochs are added. I don't see where you are setting the training optimizer, but you can also use L1/L2 regularization to update the Learning rate; this will help with overfitting, and I think this will be beneficial regardless of what decision you take for your over-fitting issue.

Now, to directly address the over-fitting issue, you can add a batch normalization Layer, adjust your dropout rate to a higher value (i.e. 0.5), and/or use recurrent dropout (you can use them together).

Batch Normalization is very helpful when data has high variance, and your batch size is already large.

The dropout and recurrent dropout only act during the training process, so there is no need to worry about affecting the inference phase.

```py
class PolicyHead(nn.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PolicyHead, self).__init__()
        self.lstm = LSTM(4,64,2,dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(64,2)

    def forward(self, past_traj):
        b,n,c = past_traj.shape
         
        return self.fc(self.lstm(past_traj, batch_id))
```

You could use them together, but the trick is to try an error, use recurrent dropout alone, try some values, and test how it behaves.

Now, if you want to apply BatchNormalization, you will need to update a little more. In your case

```py
class PolicyHead(nn.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PolicyHead, self).__init__()
        self.lstm = LSTM(4,64,2,dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3) #Assuming this is nn.LSTM
        self.batch_norm = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(64,2)

    def forward(self, past_traj):
        b,n,c = past_traj.shape
        lstm_out = self.lstm(past_traj, batch_id)[:-1:]
        return self.fc(self.batch_norm(lstm_out)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for such an attentive answer, I will try it in the future. Regarding the optimizer I am using AdamW, and have also tried many different weight decay with little success. What bothers me more is that there doesn't seem to be much trick in the paper,and the simple mlp structure wins overwhelmingly in the timing data.